# XSD Pattern for containing Quote and Apostophe

Tags: regex, xsd

How is it possible to create an regular expression within an XSD (pattern) that contains both quotes and apostrophes? I get you can check for one using the other as the value delimiters.

```
<pattern value="'"/>
<pattern value='"'/>
```

but what if you need to check for both?

```
<pattern value=""'"/>
<pattern value=''"'/>
```

simply dont work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `&apos;` or `&quot;`, for example :

```
<pattern value="&quot;|'"/>
```